# override system.assignedto value in a transition

Tags: tfs

I have a rule that in a previous transition sets a default value for the System.AssignedTo.

Now when the state changes, i want to override that value to a different user.

DEFAULT doesn't work, because there is already a value in there. I can't seem to override that value.  Anyone know how that is done?  I've tried empty then default.. but that field is also REQUIRED so empty throws an error.  Regardless that doesn't work either.

Comment: Are you trying to edit the AssignedTo field programmatically e.g. via a program you wrote using the API or is this purely in the Work Item Template? In your rule, try a COPY from Value with the value text being a typed name. Or, DEFAULT from currentuser when editing the Work Item Template in VS (if that all makes sense).

Comment: Yup tx.. i'm still getting used to TFS and those rules.. COPY is what i needed!! Thank U. you should add that as the answer.. i can't mark this as answered otherwise.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 2):

In your rule, try a COPY from Value with the value text being a typed name. Or, DEFAULT from currentuser when editing the Work Item Template in VS (if that all makes sense).